# Efficient to delete all substrings of other elements within an array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, sorting, substring

I have a complex problem of in-place editing of an array at hand.
I have an array in which some of the elements are sub-strings of other elements.I want to delete all the sub-strings and keep the supersets/strings only.
i.e. Array => `['1', '1 1', '1 1 1', '1 1 1 2', '1 2 3 1', '1 2', '2 3']`
After operation I should have a sanitized array => `['1 1 1 2', '1 2 3 1']`

Is there an efficient algorithm to achieve the same ?

Comment: Can you explain what sub string means?

Comment: Steve gave a good answer but in future please consider waiting longer before selecting an answer. Quick answers discourage other answers and may short-circuit those still working on their answers. Many here wait at least a few hours. There's no rush.

Comment: I concur with @CarySwoveland

Comment: @CarySwoveland Sure, I have undone that. I am also working on one of the solutions right now. Will post it soon.

Comment: What is the expected output if a = ["1","1","2","2"]? Do you expect [] or ["1","2"]?

Comment: @JeffPrice : Expected is ['1', '2']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses less memory, performs less computations.
This one will delete substrings both ways, looping will be less.
Brought

```
             user       system     total       real
    First    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000076)
    Second   0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.000037)
    Third    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000019)
```

Above mentioned is the benchmark results for the 2 algos mentioned above(First and Second) and this one(Third).

```
array = ['1 1 1', '1', '1 1', '1 1 1 2', '1 2 3 1', '1 2', '2 3', '1 2 3', '1 1 1']

i1 = 0
arr_len = array.length
last_index = arr_len - 1

while i1 <= last_index
  w1 = array[i1]
  i2 = i1 + 1
  while i2 <= last_index
    w2 = array[i2]
    # If w2 is a subset of w1
    if w1.include? w2
      # Delete from index i2
      array.delete_at(i2)
      # Decrement the array_length as one element is deleted
      arr_len -= 1
      # Decrement last index, as one element is deleted
      last_index -= 1
      next
    end
    # If w1 comes out to be a subset of w2
    if w2.include? w1
      # Delete the value from that index
      array.delete_at(i1)
      # Decrement the array_length as one element is deleted
      arr_len -= 1
      # Decrement last index, as one element is deleted
      last_index -= 1
      # Reset value of w1 as it is deleted in this operation
      w1 = array[i1]
      # Reset index of 2nd loop to start matching again
      i2 = i1 + 1
      # Move next from here only
      next
    end
    i2 += 1
  end
  i1 += 1
end
```

Answer (score 3):

This approach uses some array math to remove itself from the array and then checks to see if it shows up as a substring. I have no idea how performant this is.

```
a = ['1', '1 1', '1 1 1', '1 1 1 2', '1 2 3 1', '1 2', '2 3']
a.uniq.delete_if { |i| (a-[i]).any? {|j| j.include? i } }
```

I changed to using a delete_if as it will improve performance as you are shortening your array anytime a substring is found making subsequent checks slightly faster.

UPDATE: Cary Swoveland found an issue when the array contains duplicates. I have added a uniq to dedupe the array first although it's not entirely clear what should happen if an element is repeated, should both be removed since they are substrings of each other?  I have solved this problem on the assumption that duplicates result in only one item showing in the output, but this could be wrong.

Comment: What is a-[i]? I've never seen that.

Comment: @eeeeeean try it in console :) basically it is array - [element of the array]

Comment: it is an inline array that contains the element represented by i. I am doing set math by taking the existing array and subtract an array with one element from it. It was the easiest way I could think of to remove an element without worring about where it shows up in the list. It has the advantage of removing duplicates as well. In code, think of it as ['1', '1 1', '1 1 1', '1 1 1 2', '1 2 3 1', '1 2', '2 3'] - ['1']

Comment: btw, very nice solution - I like it, +oned

Comment: Sorry to pour cold water (I upvoted), but there's a problem when `a` contains duplicates, as `a-[i]` removes all elements with value `i`. For example, `a = ["1","1"]; a.delete_if { |i| (a-[i]).any? {|j| j.include? i } }
 #=> ["1", "1"]`. That's because `a-[i] #=> []`.  A fix would be to use a method I've [proposed](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11815) be added to the Ruby core: `a.delete_if { |i| (a.difference([i]).any? {|j| j.include? i } }`.

Comment: is it cheating if I just add a .uniq to resolve the issue :)

Comment: Sounds good to me (better than my suggestion). Also, that avoids mutating `a`.

Comment: Although, I'm wondering what should be the expected output of a = ["1","1"] since they are substrings of each other, perhaps the answer should be []?

Comment: I think the most reasonable interpretation is that the OP wants to eliminate "dominated" strings, which would mean that one of a group of dups should remain, provided it is not a proper substring of another string.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way that removes substrings as they are found.

```
a = ['1', '1 1', '1 1 1', '1 1 1 2', '1 2 3 1', '1 2', '2 3']

b = a.dup
b.size.times do
  first, *rest = b
  (rest.any? { |t| t.include? first }) ? b.shift : b.rotate!
end
b #=> ["1 1 1 2", "1 2 3 1"]
```

To see what's happening, insert

```
puts "first=\"#{first}\n, rest=#{rest}"
```

after `first,*rest = b`. That prints the following (before I reformatted).

```
first="1",       rest=["1 1", "1 1 1", "1 1 1 2", "1 2 3 1", "1 2", "2 3"]
first="1 1",     rest=["1 1 1", "1 1 1 2", "1 2 3 1", "1 2", "2 3"]
first="1 1 1",   rest=["1 1 1 2", "1 2 3 1", "1 2", "2 3"]
first="1 1 1 2", rest=["1 2 3 1", "1 2", "2 3"]
first="1 2 3 1", rest=["1 2", "2 3", "1 1 1 2"]
first="1 2",     rest=["2 3", "1 1 1 2", "1 2 3 1"]
first="2 3",     rest=["1 1 1 2", "1 2 3 1"]
```

Comment: I never even heard of `rotate`, +1!

Comment: Cary, I had made a simple change in my algorithm to use "delete_if" instead of reject. This had the intended side effect of removing substrings as they were found as your algorithm does. It always amazes me all the different ways to work a problem in ruby. Your use of shift and rotate is a good reminder of exploring all of the methods available in ruby.

Comment: I'm glad you mentioned the change you made. I saw your answer earlier, then after posting I saw your answer again and it seemed different than what I remembered, but I didn't notice you had edited. Good to know my short-term memory is not that bad.